# Visual C++ "Undeclared identifier" error on sprintf only in destructor

Tags: visual-c++

I have a program were I am trying to do some simple text logging to find an error that only manifests in release mode.  I have added my logging code, and it is not flagged as an error anywhere except in the class's destructor:

```
CParameterMgr::~CParameterMgr ()
{
   sprintf(logData, "Deleting m_pValueBuff (Destructor)");
   TextLogger::WriteLog(logData);

   delete [] m_pValueBuff;
}
```

I am actually getting "error C2065: 'sprintf' : undeclared identifier"

Can anyone explain why sprintf cannot be used in a destructor?

Thanks

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

Comment: That was it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

No limitation on usage of sprintf in destructor exists.
You just forgot include appropriate header file.

C-style way is

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

C++-style way is

```
#include <cstdio>
```